# Oracle Data Dump and Data Restore

Tags: mysql, oracle, export

What's the "standard" (defacto or otherwise) way to dump an Oracle database/instance to an ascii or binary file, and then reimport that file into a separate Oracle instance.

I'm looking for the equivalent of `mysqldump`, but for the Oracle platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I'm pretty sure imp + exp have been superceeded by Oracle Data Pump.

imp + exp do not support all Oracle 10g + 11g features

See  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the Oracle Import / Export utility:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ